# How can I add a photo to the questions?

Tags: javascript, html, json

**I want to add a photo to the questions that when a question also the photo.**
each question can have a photo.
each question can have a photo.

and you can show it next to the question.
each question can have a photo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  // event listeners
  $("#remaining-time").hide();
  $("#start").on('click', trivia.startGame);
  $(document).on('click' , '.option', trivia.guessChecker);

})

var trivia = {
  // trivia properties
  correct: 0,
  incorrect: 0,
  unanswered: 0,
  currentSet: 0,
  timer: 20,
  timerOn: false,
  timerId : '',
  // questions options and answers data
  questions: {
    q1: 'Who is actually a chef?',
    q2: 'What does Joey love to eat?',
    q3: 'How many times has Ross been divorced?',
    q4: 'How many types of towels does Monica have?',
    q5: "Who stole Monica's thunder after she got engaged?",
    q6: 'Who hates Thanksgiving?',
    q7: "Who thinks they're always the last to find out everything?"
  },
  options: {
    q1: ['Monica', 'Chandler', 'Rachel', 'Ross'],
    q2: ['Fish', 'Apples', 'Oranges', 'Sandwhiches'],
    q3: ['5', '2', '1', '3'],
    q4: ['3', '8', '11', '6'],
    q5: ['Rachel','Phoebe','Emily','Carol'],
    q6: ['Joey','Chandler','Rachel','Ross'],
    q7: ['Ross', 'Phoebe', 'Monica','Chandler']
  },
  answers: {
    q1: 'Monica',
    q2: 'Sandwhiches',
    q3: '3',
    q4: '11',
    q5: 'Rachel',
    q6: 'Chandler',
    q7: 'Phoebe'
  },
  // trivia methods
  // method to initialize game
  startGame: function(){
    // restarting game results
    trivia.currentSet = 0;
    trivia.correct = 0;
    trivia.incorrect = 0;
    trivia.unanswered = 0;
    clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
    
    // show game section
    $('#game').show();
    
    //  empty last results
    $('#results').html('');
    
    // show timer
    $('#timer').text(trivia.timer);
    
    // remove start button
    $('#start').hide();

    $('#remaining-time').show();
    
    // ask first question
    trivia.nextQuestion();
    
  },
  // method to loop through and display questions and options 
  nextQuestion : function(){
    
    // set timer to 20 seconds each question
    trivia.timer = 10;
     $('#timer').removeClass('last-seconds');
    $('#timer').text(trivia.timer);
    
    // to prevent timer speed up
    if(!trivia.timerOn){
      trivia.timerId = setInterval(trivia.timerRunning, 1000);
    }
    
    // gets all the questions then indexes the current questions
    var questionContent = Object.values(trivia.questions)[trivia.currentSet];
    $('#question').text(questionContent);
    
    // an array of all the user options for the current question
    var questionOptions = Object.values(trivia.options)[trivia.currentSet];
    
    // creates all the trivia guess options in the html
    $.each(questionOptions, function(index, key){
      $('#options').append($('<button class="option btn btn-info btn-lg">'+key+'</button>'));
    })
    
  },
  // method to decrement counter and count unanswered if timer runs out
  timerRunning : function(){
    // if timer still has time left and there are still questions left to ask
    if(trivia.timer > -1 && trivia.currentSet < Object.keys(trivia.questions).length){
      $('#timer').text(trivia.timer);
      trivia.timer--;
        if(trivia.timer === 4){
          $('#timer').addClass('last-seconds');
        }
    }
    // the time has run out and increment unanswered, run result
    else if(trivia.timer === -1){
      trivia.unanswered++;
      trivia.result = false;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $('#results').html('<h3>Out of time! The answer was '+ Object.values(trivia.answers)[trivia.currentSet] +'</h3>');
    }
    // if all the questions have been shown end the game, show results
    else if(trivia.currentSet === Object.keys(trivia.questions).length){
      
      // adds results of game (correct, incorrect, unanswered) to the page
      $('#results')
        .html('<h3>Thank you for playing!</h3>'+
        '<p>Correct: '+ trivia.correct +'</p>'+
        '<p>Incorrect: '+ trivia.incorrect +'</p>'+
        '<p>Unaswered: '+ trivia.unanswered +'</p>'+
        '<p>Please play again!</p>');
      
      // hide game sction
      $('#game').hide();
      
      // show start button to begin a new game
      $('#start').show();
    }
    
  },
  // method to evaluate the option clicked
  guessChecker : function() {
    
    // timer ID for gameResult setTimeout
    var resultId;
    
    // the answer to the current question being asked
    var currentAnswer = Object.values(trivia.answers)[trivia.currentSet];
    
    //''if the text of the option picked matches ''''the answer of the current question, increment correct
    if($(this).text() === currentAnswer){
      //turn button green for correct
      $(this).addClass('btn-success').removeClass('btn-info');
      
      trivia.correct++;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $('#results').html('<h3>Correct Answer!</h3>');
    }
    // else the user picked the wrong option, increment incorrect
    else{
      // turn button clicked red for incorrect
      $(this).addClass('btn-danger').removeClass('btn-info');
      
      trivia.incorrect++;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $('#results').html('<h3>Better luck next time! '+ currentAnswer +'</h3>');
    }
    
  },
  //method to remove previous question results and options
  guessResult : function(){
    
    // increment to next question set
    trivia.currentSet++;
    
    // remove the options and results
    $('.option').remove();
    $('#results h3').remove();
    
    // begin next question
    trivia.nextQuestion();
     
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Trivia Game</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/Jaymar/SMU_HW/week5/TriviaGame/assets/css/style.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="./assets/images/IMG_3456.jpg"/>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<!--    <link href="jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

  </head>

  <body>
  
    <audio controls loop>
      <source src="./assets/images/tumblr_lq9mbjMc3g1qas0n5o1.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
    </audio>
   
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header text-center clearfix">
        <h1 class="text-muted">Friends trivia game</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">
        <div id="game">
          <h2>FRIENDS Trivia Game</h2>
          <p id="remaining-time" class="lead">Remaining Time: <span id="timer"></span></p>
          <p id="question" class="lead"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="results">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div id="choices" class="text-center">
          <button id="start" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Start Game</button>
          <div id="options">
            
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- jQuery CDN-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- TRIVIA APP JS -->
    <script src="./assets/js/app.js"></script>  


  </body>
</html>
```

**this is the html code to show the questions and answers, I hope it can be done randomly**

thanks

Comment: Please add your HTML where you displaying all questions and options.

Comment: Hello, I already updated the code so you can see it

Comment: whenever click on start game question to be display randomly ?

Comment: Added answer @DanielLopez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it done, each time a new question is requested it should be randomly taken, you'll need a random number generator and a little bit of code tweaking :

> I deleted your comments so you could easily spot the tweaks as I commented each new line added to the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#remaining-time").hide();
  $("#start").on("click", trivia.startGame);
  $(document).on("click", ".option", trivia.guessChecker);
});

var trivia = {
    correct: 0,
    incorrect: 0,
    unanswered: 0,
    currentSet: 0,
    // "seen" property will keep track of the seen questions so we don't re-display them again
    seen: [],
    // Update: limit the number of question per game. Usong a property so you can change its value whenever you want to change the limit
    limit: 4,
    timer: 20,
    timerOn: false,
    timerId: "",
    // questions options and answers data
    questions: {
      q1: "Who is actually a chef?",
      q2: "What does Joey love to eat?",
      q3: "How many times has Ross been divorced?",
      q4: "How many types of towels does Monica have?",
      q5: "Who stole Monica's thunder after she got engaged?",
      q6: "Who hates Thanksgiving?",
      q7: "Who thinks they're always the last to find out everything?"
    },
    options: {
      q1: ["Monica", "Chandler", "Rachel", "Ross"],
      q2: ["Fish", "Apples", "Oranges", "Sandwhiches"],
      q3: ["5", "2", "1", "3"],
      q4: ["3", "8", "11", "6"],
      q5: ["Rachel", "Phoebe", "Emily", "Carol"],
      q6: ["Joey", "Chandler", "Rachel", "Ross"],
      q7: ["Ross", "Phoebe", "Monica", "Chandler"]
    },
    answers: {
      q1: "Monica",
      q2: "Sandwhiches",
      q3: "3",
      q4: "11",
      q5: "Rachel",
      q6: "Chandler",
      q7: "Phoebe"
    },
    // random number generator
    random: (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min,
    startGame: function() {
      trivia.currentSet = 0;
      // set "seen" to an empty array for a new game
      trivia.seen = [];
      trivia.correct = 0;
      trivia.incorrect = 0;
      trivia.unanswered = 0;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      $("#game").show();
      $("#results").html("");
      $("#timer").text(trivia.timer);
      $("#start").hide();
      $("#remaining-time").show();
      trivia.nextQuestion();
    },
    nextQuestion: function() {
      trivia.timer = 10;
      $("#timer").removeClass("last-seconds");
      $("#timer").text(trivia.timer);
      if (!trivia.timerOn) {
        trivia.timerId = setInterval(trivia.timerRunning, 1000);
      }
      // get all the questions
      const qts = Object.values(trivia.questions);
      // init the random number
      let rq = null;
      // firstly, if no more questions to show set rq to -1 to let us know later that the game has finished 
      // Update: checking if we reached the "limit"
      if (trivia.seen.length >= trivia.limit) rq = -1
      else {
        // otherwise generate a random number from 0 inclusive to the length of the questions - 1 (as array indexing starts from 0 in JS) also inclusive
        do {
          // generate a random number using the newly added "random" method
          rq = trivia.random(0, qts.length - 1);
        } while (trivia.seen.indexOf(rq) != -1); // if the question is already seen then genrate another number, do that till we get a non-seen question index
        // add that randomly generated index to the seen array so we know that we have already seen it
        trivia.seen.push(rq);
        // increment the counter
        trivia.counter++;
      }
      // current question index is the generated random number "rq"
      trivia.currentSet = rq;
      var questionContent = Object.values(trivia.questions)[rq];
      $("#question").text(questionContent);
      var questionOptions = Object.values(trivia.options)[trivia.currentSet];
      $.each(questionOptions, function(index, key) {
        $("#options").append(
          $('<button class="option btn btn-info btn-lg">' + key + "</button>")
        );
      });
    },
    timerRunning: function() {
      if (
        trivia.timer > -1 &&
        // all the questions have already been seen
        // Update: now we check against the limit property
        trivia.seen.length < trivia.limit
    ) {
      $("#timer").text(trivia.timer);
      trivia.timer--;
      if (trivia.timer === 4) {
        $("#timer").addClass("last-seconds");
      }
    } else if (trivia.timer === -1) {
      trivia.unanswered++;
      trivia.result = false;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $("#results").html(
        "<h3>Out of time! The answer was " +
        Object.values(trivia.answers)[trivia.currentSet] +
        "</h3>"
      );
    }
    // if the game ended as we know that -1 means no more questions to display
    else if (trivia.currentSet === -1) {
      $("#results").html(
        "<h3>Thank you for playing!</h3>" +
        "<p>Correct: " +
        trivia.correct +
        "</p>" +
        "<p>Incorrect: " +
        trivia.incorrect +
        "</p>" +
        "<p>Unaswered: " +
        trivia.unanswered +
        "</p>" +
        "<p>Please play again!</p>"
      );
      $("#game").hide();
      $("#start").show();
    }
  },
  guessChecker: function() {
    var resultId;
    var currentAnswer = Object.values(trivia.answers)[trivia.currentSet];
    if ($(this).text() === currentAnswer) {
      //turn button green for correct
      $(this).addClass("btn-success").removeClass("btn-info");
      trivia.correct++;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $("#results").html("<h3>Correct Answer!</h3>");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("btn-danger").removeClass("btn-info");

      trivia.incorrect++;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $("#results").html(
        "<h3>Better luck next time! " + currentAnswer + "</h3>"
      );
    }
  },

  guessResult: function() {
    // no need to increment trivia.currentSet anymore
    $(".option").remove();
    $("#results h3").remove();
    trivia.nextQuestion();
  }
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header text-center clearfix">
    <h1 class="text-muted">Friends trivia game</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="game">
        <h2>FRIENDS Trivia Game</h2>
        <p id="remaining-time" class="lead">Remaining Time: <span id="timer"></span></p>
        <p id="question" class="lead"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="results">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="choices" class="text-center">
        <button id="start" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Start Game</button>
        <div id="options">

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I needed it

Comment: Upvoting answer. This is another approach to achieve same result. @ths

Comment: Can you limit the number of questions, for example, only 4 are answered?         I have many questions but I just want to show 4 and finish the execution

Comment: could you help me?

Comment: Yes, you can. I'll update my answer to allow only four questions per game.

Comment: @DanielLopez answer updated, only 4 question per game. Also, you can change that limit by changing the value of `limit` property.

Comment: @ths hello ths, this code can in some questions bring an image depending on the question?

Comment: could you help me please

Comment: @ths please help

Comment: Yes  you can with some changes. But I think you'd better ask a new question for clarity and also to allow the community to benefit more.

Comment: @ths can you help me with that, is that I made the query but nobody could help me with what I asked you, Please. How can I add a photo to the questions?

Comment: @DanielLopez I saw your new question buty it seems that you're keeping the old code ? Why won't you use the code I helped you with ? If you can, then edit your new question with the new code (my answer here) so I can point you to how you'd add an image without covering the old code's issues and mistakes.

Comment: @ths I already added a new question about that, maybe you can help me, I leave the link. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62819288/how-can-i-add-a-photo-to-all-displayed-questions)

Comment: @DanielLopez great, I'll check it out.

Comment: @ths sorry for the inconvenience, could you help me?

Comment: @DanielLopez sorry for your time, im a little busy at the moment but i'll check your question ASAP.

Comment: @ths Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  // event listeners
  $("#remaining-time").hide();
  $("#start").on('click', trivia.startGame);
  $(document).on('click' , '.option', trivia.guessChecker);

})

var trivia = {
  // trivia properties
  correct: 0,
  incorrect: 0,
  unanswered: 0,
  currentSet: 0,
  timer: 20,
  timerOn: false,
  timerId : '',
  // questions options and answers data
  questions: {
    q1: 'Who is actually a chef?',
    q2: 'What does Joey love to eat?',
    q3: 'How many times has Ross been divorced?',
    q4: 'How many types of towels does Monica have?',
    q5: "Who stole Monica's thunder after she got engaged?",
    q6: 'Who hates Thanksgiving?',
    q7: "Who thinks they're always the last to find out everything?"
  },
  options: {
    q1: ['Monica', 'Chandler', 'Rachel', 'Ross'],
    q2: ['Fish', 'Apples', 'Oranges', 'Sandwhiches'],
    q3: ['5', '2', '1', '3'],
    q4: ['3', '8', '11', '6'],
    q5: ['Rachel','Phoebe','Emily','Carol'],
    q6: ['Joey','Chandler','Rachel','Ross'],
    q7: ['Ross', 'Phoebe', 'Monica','Chandler']
  },
  answers: {
    q1: 'Monica',
    q2: 'Sandwhiches',
    q3: '3',
    q4: '11',
    q5: 'Rachel',
    q6: 'Chandler',
    q7: 'Phoebe'
  },
  // trivia methods
  // method to initialize game
  startGame: function(){
    // restarting game results
    trivia.currentSet = 0;
    trivia.correct = 0;
    trivia.incorrect = 0;
    trivia.unanswered = 0;
    clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
    
    // show game section
    $('#game').show();
    
    //  empty last results
    $('#results').html('');
    
    // show timer
    $('#timer').text(trivia.timer);
    
    // remove start button
    $('#start').hide();

    $('#remaining-time').show();
    
    // ask first question
    
    trivia.questions = randomizeObject(trivia.questions);
    //console.log(trivia.questions);
    
    trivia.nextQuestion();
    
  },
  // method to loop through and display questions and options 
  nextQuestion : function(){
    
    // set timer to 20 seconds each question
    trivia.timer = 10;
     $('#timer').removeClass('last-seconds');
    $('#timer').text(trivia.timer);
    
    // to prevent timer speed up
    if(!trivia.timerOn){
      trivia.timerId = setInterval(trivia.timerRunning, 1000);
    }
    //console.log(trivia.questions);
    // gets all the questions then indexes the current questions
    //console.log(Object.values(trivia.questions)[trivia.currentSet]);
    var questionContent = Object.values(trivia.questions)[trivia.currentSet];
    $('#question').text(questionContent);
    
    // an array of all the user options for the current question
    var questionOptions = Object.values(trivia.options)[trivia.currentSet];
    
    // creates all the trivia guess options in the html
    $.each(questionOptions, function(index, key){
      $('#options').append($('<button class="option btn btn-info btn-lg">'+key+'</button>'));
    })
    
  },
  // method to decrement counter and count unanswered if timer runs out
  timerRunning : function(){
    // if timer still has time left and there are still questions left to ask
    if(trivia.timer > -1 && trivia.currentSet < Object.keys(trivia.questions).length){
      $('#timer').text(trivia.timer);
      trivia.timer--;
        if(trivia.timer === 4){
          $('#timer').addClass('last-seconds');
        }
    }
    // the time has run out and increment unanswered, run result
    else if(trivia.timer === -1){
      trivia.unanswered++;
      trivia.result = false;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $('#results').html('<h3>Out of time! The answer was '+ Object.values(trivia.answers)[trivia.currentSet] +'</h3>');
    }
    // if all the questions have been shown end the game, show results
    else if(trivia.currentSet === Object.keys(trivia.questions).length){
      
      // adds results of game (correct, incorrect, unanswered) to the page
      $('#results')
        .html('<h3>Thank you for playing!</h3>'+
        '<p>Correct: '+ trivia.correct +'</p>'+
        '<p>Incorrect: '+ trivia.incorrect +'</p>'+
        '<p>Unaswered: '+ trivia.unanswered +'</p>'+
        '<p>Please play again!</p>');
      
      // hide game sction
      $('#game').hide();
      
      // show start button to begin a new game
      $('#start').show();
    }
    
  },
  // method to evaluate the option clicked
  guessChecker : function() {
    
    // timer ID for gameResult setTimeout
    var resultId;
    
    // the answer to the current question being asked
    var currentAnswer = Object.values(trivia.answers)[trivia.currentSet];
    
    //''if the text of the option picked matches ''''the answer of the current question, increment correct
    if($(this).text() === currentAnswer){
      //turn button green for correct
      $(this).addClass('btn-success').removeClass('btn-info');
      
      trivia.correct++;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $('#results').html('<h3>Correct Answer!</h3>');
    }
    // else the user picked the wrong option, increment incorrect
    else{
      // turn button clicked red for incorrect
      $(this).addClass('btn-danger').removeClass('btn-info');
      
      trivia.incorrect++;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $('#results').html('<h3>Better luck next time! '+ currentAnswer +'</h3>');
    }
    
  },
  //method to remove previous question results and options
  guessResult : function(){
    
    // increment to next question set
    trivia.currentSet++;
    
    // remove the options and results
    $('.option').remove();
    $('#results h3').remove();
    
    // begin next question
    trivia.nextQuestion();
     
  }

}
function randomizeObject(obj){
  let newObj = {};
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    keys.sort(function(a,b){return Math.random()- 0.5;});
    keys.forEach(function(k) {
        newObj[k] = obj[k];
});
//console.log(newObj);
  return newObj;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Trivia Game</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/Jaymar/SMU_HW/week5/TriviaGame/assets/css/style.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="./assets/images/IMG_3456.jpg"/>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<!--    <link href="jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

  </head>

  <body>
  
    <audio controls loop>
      <source src="./assets/images/tumblr_lq9mbjMc3g1qas0n5o1.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
    </audio>
   
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header text-center clearfix">
        <h1 class="text-muted">Friends trivia game</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">
        <div id="game">
          <h2>FRIENDS Trivia Game</h2>
          <p id="remaining-time" class="lead">Remaining Time: <span id="timer"></span></p>
          <p id="question" class="lead"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="results">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div id="choices" class="text-center">
          <button id="start" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Start Game</button>
          <div id="options">
            
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- jQuery CDN-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- TRIVIA APP JS -->
    <script src="./assets/js/app.js"></script>  


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this help you dont forget to upvote answer and accept. Thanks! @DanielLopez

Comment: the answers are not those of the questions, could it be solved?